# If A is invertible and $||B-A|| < ||A^{-1}||^{-1}$ prove $B$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Just having really hard time trying to proof :

If $A$ is invertible and $||B-A|| < ||A^{-1}||^{-1}$ prove $B$ is invertible.

It is related to Neumann Series but i don't understand how to proof with math.

Thanks for your help and time.

Brian Ignacio

Comment: Can you specify what matrix norm you are using? There are different such norms.

Comment: So sorry for the bad format and tagging. Will keep in mind next time. Thank you.

Comment: That is the thing, there no specific detail about which type of norm is it. The only thing i know is that A,B are matrices. The problem is in Kincaid book of Numerical Analysis.

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume that $\|A\|$ denotes the **supremum norm**, that is, for $A \in \mathrm{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbb R)$ (or $\mathbb C$), 
$$
\|A\| \overset{def}= \sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|},
$$
where $\|x\|$ is the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C^n$. 
Your inequality implies
$$
\|BA^{-1} - I\| \le \|A^{-1}\|\|B-A\| < 1
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. Therefore it suffices to treat the case where $A = I$ is the identity matrix.

If $\|B-I\| < 1$, then by definition of the norm all the eigenvalues of $B$ are non-zero. Writing $B$ in Jordan form, one sees that it suffices to invert Jordan blocks.

Writing a Jordan block as $\lambda I + N$ where $N$ is nilpotent (this $N$ is the matrix of all $1$'s on the second diagonal), we see that 
$$
(\lambda I + N)^{-1} = \frac 1{\lambda} \left(I + \frac 1{\lambda} N \right)^{-1} = \sum_{i \ge 0} \frac{(-N)^i}{\lambda^{i+1}}
$$
(this is the geometric series formula, but for a nilpotent matrix this series is finite, so it is well-defined). If you know the proof of the geometric sum formula, this is the same proof, but the elements are matrices instead of complex numbers ; it shows that 
$$
(I-N)\left( \sum_{i=0}^m N^i \right) = I - N^{m+1}
$$
for any matrix $N$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Since $\|B-I\|<1$ and you said that all the eigenvalues of $B$ are non-zero, can't we conclude that $B$ is invertible? (The subtle point for this my question will be whether $B$ has *real* eigenvalues? In this case, we can first complexify (extend) $B$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$; the norm of $B$ operating on $\mathbb{C}^n$ will be same as that on $\mathbb{R}^n$, is it correct? I may be wrong, but my main question is first line of my comment with this justification)

Comment: @Beginner : If $B$ were diagonalizable, then you don't need to say much to conclude that $B$ is invertible ; you can write the inverse matrix over the eigenbasis of $B$ by just inverting the eigenvalues of $B$. The case of $\|B-I\| < 1$ that I proved essentially shows how to compute the inverse of $B$ over a generalized eigenbasis (the basis over which $B$ is in Jordan normal form) by restricting to the case where $B$ itself is a Jordan block with non-zero eigenvalue. The inequality $\|B-I\| < 1$ does not tell you if the eigenvalues are real or not.

Comment: @Beginner : The reason why I do this thing with the Jordan blocks is precisely because the matrix norm of $B-I$ and its complexification are not going to be the same in general (in fact, the complex norm of $B-I$ is always going to be $\le$ the real norm, since the supremum of the complex norm is taken over a larger set as in the supremum of the real norm).

Answer (score 3):

The hypotheses imply that $r := ||B-A||\cdot ||A^{-1}|| < 1$. Thus the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$ converges absolutely.

In particular $||BA^{-1} - I||\leq ||B-A||\cdot ||A^{-1}||= r < 1$.

Thus $A^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-(BA^{-1}-I))^k = `` A^{-1}\frac{1}{I+(BA^{-1}-I)} "$ is absolutely convergent and you can check that it is the inverse of $B$.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I think it deserves a simple solution which does not need a convergence argument. So here we go.

By assumption, we have $\| A-B \| \| A^{-1}\| < 1$. Moreover because the induced $2$-norm is consistent, we have $\| (A-B)A^{-1}\|\leq \| A-B \| \| A^{-1}\|$. Therefore, $\| (A-B)A^{-1}\|=\|I-BA^{-1} \|<1$. Now we show that $BA^{-1}$ is invertible. For the sake of contradiction, suppose that $BA^{-1}$ is singular. Then there exists $v\neq 0$ such that $BA^{-1}v = 0$. Without loss of generality, we assume $\|v\|_2=1$ (if not, we can take $v/\|v\|_2$). Now by the triangle property, we have

$$1=\|v\|_2\leq \|v-BA^{-1}v\|_2+\|BA^{-1}v\|_2 = \|(I-BA^{-1})v \|_2\leq \| I- BA^{-1}\|,
$$
where the second equality follows from $BA^{-1}v = 0$, and the last inequality follows from the definition of the induced matrix norm and $\|v\|_2=1$. This is a contradiction, because previously, we showed that $\|I-BA^{-1} \|<1$. Therefore, the invertibility of $BA^{-1}$ follows from this contradiction. Now one can easily see that $A^{-1}(BA^{-1})^{-1}$ is the inverse of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general result in a [Banach algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra). The algebra of linear operators on a finite dimensional space is a Banach algebra, but you also have many examples of infinite dimensional Banach algebra. For example the algebra of all bounded continuous real functions on some compact space (with pointwise operations and supremum norm) is a Banach algebra.

The norm on a Banach algebra satisfies the inequality $$\Vert A B \Vert \le \Vert A \Vert \Vert B \Vert.$$

Based on that, you can use the Neumann series, as suggested in your original question. For $\Vert U \Vert < 1$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ you have
$$(1-U)\sum_{k=0}^n U^k =U^{n+1} \tag{1}$$ and $\sum_{k=0}^n U^k$ converges normally to an element $$S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty U^k$$ and the equality (1) proves that $S$ is the inverse of $1-U$.

Coming back to your original question and using the initial answer of [Patrick Da Silva](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/10704/patrick-da-silva), you get that $BA^{-1}=U$ is invertible. Hence $B$ is also invertible.

Comment: Of course this generalizes to the context where you strictly have the properties required so that the proof works (and it's good that you can see it), but when OP says he does not know ''how to proof with math'', I don't think he wants to work with such great generality.