# Question regarding $l_2$-space.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

> > For $x=(x_n) \in l_2$, define
> >
> > $T(x)=(0,x_1,x_2, \cdots)$ and $S(x)=(x_2,x_3, \cdots)$.
> >
> > Which of the following statements are true?
> >
> > $(a)$ $\|T\| = \|S\|=1$.
> >
> > $(b)$ If $A: l_2 \longrightarrow l_2$ is a continuous linear operator such that $\|A-T\|<1$, then $SA$ is invertible.
> >
> > $(c)$ If $A$ is as above, then $A$ is not invertible.

$(a)$ is true which is easy to show. But I have no clue regarding $(b)$ and $(c)$. Would anybody please help me in this regard?

Thank you very much.

Comment: For 2, do you know about inverse approximations: If $B$ is invertible and $\|A -B\| < \|B^{-1}\|^{-1}$ then $A$ is invertible? For 1, try some examples.

Comment: Yes I know @4-ier.

Comment: But what is $B$ here?

Comment: Hint: What is $ST$?

Comment: $(1)$ is trivially true.

Comment: @DebabrataChattopadhyay. what if $x_1 \neq 0$?

Comment: ST is identity on $l_2$.

Comment: Is c true @4-ier.

Comment: $\|SA-ST\|=\|S(A-T)\| \leq \|S\|\|A-T\| <$ $\|S\| = \|I\| = \|(ST)^{-1}\|^{-1}$, proving that $SA$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

1. $\lVert Tx \rVert = \lVert x \rVert$, thus $\lVert T \rVert \le 1$. Using $x = (1, 0, \dots)$ we have $\lVert x \rVert = 1$ and $\lVert Tx \rVert = 1$ as well. Hence $\lVert T \rVert = 1$.

   $ST = Id \Rightarrow 1 = \lVert ST \rVert \le \lVert S \rVert 1 \Rightarrow \lVert S \rVert \ge 1$. We also have $\lVert Sx \rVert \le \lVert x \rVert$, hence $\lVert S \rVert = 1$.
2. [4-ier](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/586179/4-ier) gave the solution in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890660/question-regarding-l-2-space#comment5969473_2890660): If $C$ is invertible and $\lVert C - D \rVert < \lVert C^{-1} \rVert^{-1}$, then $D$ is invertible as well.

   Apply this on the invertible operator $ST$: $\|SA-ST\|=\|S(A-T)\| \leq \|S\|\|A-T\| < \|S\| = \|I\| = \|(ST)^{-1}\|^{-1}$

   You can find a proof outline at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1508092/571891.
3. If $A$ were invertible, then per (2) $SAA^{-1} = S$ would be invertible as well. However, $S$ is clearly not injective.