# Proof that $\|S-T\| < \|S^{-1}\|^{-1}$ implies $T$ is invertible if $S$ is invertible

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ ($\mathcal{L}(X)$ is the set of bounded linear operator on $X$). Assume there exists an invertible operator $S \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ (invertible = bijective + bounded inverse).
I want to proof that $\|S-T\|<\|S^{-1}\|^{-1}$ implies that $T$ is invertible as well.

Proof:
I know (Neumann series) that for an operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ with $\|T\|<|\lambda|$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ it holds that $\lambda I-T$ is invertible. It then follows (with $\lambda = 1$) that $\|I-T\|<1$ implies $I-(I-T)=T$ is invertible.

Using the assumption from above it follows that $\|I-S^{-1}T\|=\|S^{-1}(S-T)\|\leq \|S^{-1}\|\, \| S-T\|<1$. Therefore $S^{-1}T$ is invertible (bijective and bounded inverse).
Changing the order of composition yields $\|I-TS^{-1}\|=\|(S-T)S^{-1}\|\leq \|S^{-1}\|\, \| S-T\|<1$ and therefore $TS^{-1}$ is invertible as well.
For compositions it holds that:

- $f\circ g$ injective $\Rightarrow$ $g$ injective
- $f\circ g$ surjective $\Rightarrow$ $f$ surjective

We can therefore conclude from $S^{-1}T=S^{-1} \circ T$ being injective that $T$ is injective and from $TS^{-1}=T \circ S^{-1}$ being surjective that $T$ is surjective and thus that $T$ is bijective. Due to the bounded inverse theorem every bijective operator between Banach spaces has a bounded inverse and therefore $T$ is invertible.

Is my proof correct?
Is there a faster / shoorter proof?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If A is invertible and $||B-A|| &lt; ||A^{-1}||^{-1}$ prove $B$ is invertible.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508035/if-a-is-invertible-and-b-a-a-1-1-prove-b-is-invertible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you know that $S^{-1}T$ is invertible, the job is over:

let $U:=(S^{-1}T)^{-1}$, then $T$ is invertible, with inverse $V:=US^{-1}$, since

- $VT=US^{-1}T=I$;
- $S^{-1}TU=I$, hence $TV=SIS^{-1}=I$.

Comment: Ah, of course. If $V \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ and $TV=VT=I$ then $V=T^{-1}$. Thanks.

Comment: I had to proof this again in another context. While the conclusion is clear I don't understand why $TV=SIS^{-1}$ holds?

Comment: @bayes2021 because $S^{-1}TU=I\implies TUS^{-1}=SIS^{-1},$ and $US^{-1}=V.$