# Intuitively explain why $U: X \rightarrow X$ is invertible if it is close enough to the identity operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. The Neumann theorem states that an operator $U: X \rightarrow X$ is invertible if it is close enough to the identity operator. This is the theorem.

> If $U: X \rightarrow X$ is bounded and $\|I-U\|<1$, then $U$ is invertible, and
> $$
> U^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(I-U)^k
> $$
> Furthermore,
> $$
> \left\|U^{-1}\right\| \leq \frac{1}{1-\|I-U\|}
> $$

I'm not interested in the proof of this theorem, but why $I$ is so important for it? I mean, can I (for example) substitute the operator $I$ with another one and then obtain a similar theorem?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4538283/proof-that-s-t-s-1-1-implies-t-is-invertible-if-s-is-inver?rq=1
Basically you can take $I$ to be any invertible operator $S$ if you replace $1$ on the right-hand side by $\|S^{-1}\|^{-1}$, which for $I$ is $1$.

Comment: Identity  $I$ is very particular as operator. Besides close enough in norm is not close enough as operator. Take $X=\mathbb R$ and try to get an example let you to see clearly the point.

Comment: @Piquito thank you, I will follow your comment

Comment: @G.Gare thanks, the quoted question is interesting. But I didn't understand which right-hand side you are referring to. Could you add some details, please?

Comment: Note that if $A$ is invertible, then $A^{-1} U$ and $U$ are invertible simultaneously. So, try to substitute $U$ with $A^{-1}U$ in the series, and check what will be the requirement for absolute convergence.

Comment: @Mark the upper bound of the condition $\|I - U\| < 1$ is $1$. In case you replace $I$ by any invertible operator $S$, you can replace $1$ by $\|S^{-1}\|^{-1}$ and the condition $\|S - U\| < \|S^{-1}\|^{-1}$ with boundedness of $U$ is sufficient to imply that $U$ is invertible. This means that $I$ is not "so important", it's just a special case of any invertible operator $S$ which has the special property of satisfying $\|I^{-1}\|^{-1}=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T$ is any invertible operator and $\|T-U\|<\|T^{-1}\|^{-1}$, then
$$
\|I-T^{-1}U\|=\|T^{-1}(T-U)\|\leq\|T^{-1}\|\,\|T-U\|<1,
$$
and then by the result quoted in the question you haveh $T^{-1}U$ invertible, which then implies that $U$ is invertible. What this shows is that the set of invertible operators is open; that is, any operator sufficiently close in norm to an invertible operator is invertible.

On an intuitive level, an invertible operator is bounded below: $\|Tx\|\geq c\|x\|$ for all $x$. If $\|T-U\|<c$, then $\|U-T\|<\delta<c$ and
$$
\|Ux\|=\|Tx+(U-T)x\|\geq\|Tx\|-\|(U-T)x\|\geq c\,\|x\|-\delta\,\|x\|=(c-\delta)\,\|x\|
$$
and $U$ is bounded below (hence injective). Being bounded below $U$ has closed range. If $U$ is not surjective, given $y\in (\operatorname{ran}U)^\perp$ there exists $x$ such that $Tx=y$. By scaling if necessary, we may assume that $\|x\|=1$. Then $Tx\perp Ux$, and so
$$
\|T-U\|\geq\|Tx-Ux\|=\sqrt{\|Tx\|^2+\|Ux\|^2}\geq\|Tx\|\geq c,
$$
a contradiction. Hence $U$ is bijective, and so invertible by the Inverse Mapping Theorem.
In summary, if $\|T-U\|<c$ then $U$ is invertible.